# HTML Class Syntax

Tags: html

Please check the below image by clicking on it.

Here at Preview side, how to put the ">" in starting of Previous Text.

Please help me on this.

```html
<lui-button 
class="button1"  ng-click="navigation.prevSheet();app.clearAll();"
ng-style="{color: settings.color}">Previous 

<span class="lui-icon lui-icon--arrow-left">
</span>

</lui-button>
```

[Please check the code image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5cZD.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: this isn't strict html .. is it?

Comment: By simply writing `>`? If you want icon, then you are missing some CSS for `lui-icon`

Comment: This is not raw HTML, it's meant to be post-processed with JavaScript, so the snippet is not going to work here. Are you using Angular?

Comment: Hi I am a BI developer. I am looking for HTML Script to create button like           "< Previous"  with sheet navigation action and clearall filters action. The total code is working fine but I am getting "Previous >" instead of "< Previous". In Qliksense tool we can able to runt he HTML Code.

Comment: @Mahitham a button syntax is just `<button>hello world</button>` - use resources like MDN and W3C to research this ...

Comment: This is icons from https://qlik-oss.github.io/leonardo-ui/get-started.html
You need to install  that font via NPM or download directly to your project.

Comment: @treyBack by above syntax will get the output like hello world in button. I am looking to add "<" icon before hello world i.e., "< hello world" Please provide the syntax.

Comment: Single left-pointing angle quotation mark (U+2039): ‹

Comment: oh.. then you want to use `html entity codes`: for you: `&lt;` -> <

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this project is using https://github.com/qlik-oss/leonardo-ui. A UI framework. 
If you just need an icons - there is free and simple icon font https://fontawesome.com/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button 
class="button1"  ng-click="navigation.prevSheet();app.clearAll();"
ng-style="{color: settings.color}">

<i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>

Previous</button>
```

Comment: Hi I am looking for how to show < (left icon) before Previous like <Previous

Comment: @Mahitham just put that `span` tag before text then. Like this `<lui-button ... ><span class="lui-icon lui-icon--arrow-left">
</span>Previous</lui-button>`

Comment: @Mahitham Unfortunately, I will not be able to fix my snippet for your working code, since that framework is not supported here. I will correct my own example of another font tho.  Accept my answer to indicate that the issue is resolved.